# Isim is not testing all bits in test fixture

Tags: testing, verilog, simulation, hdl, xilinx-ise

I am trying to test all possible cases of inputs for my Verilog code. I set it up with for loops.

```
for(sel = 0;sel < 4;sel=sel+1) begin
            for(a = 0;a < 8;a=a+1) begin
                    for(b = 0;b < 8;b=b+1) begin
                        #50;
                    end
            end
    end
```

It was working earlier, but I must have changed something or Isim might have a bug. 
I initialized a, b and sel, too.

```
reg [2:0] a;
reg [2:0] b;
reg [1:0] sel;
```

When I try to simulate the tb file, it only loops through b repeatedly!
Why could this be?

Also, when I change b bounds to <7, it will begin to loop through a, but I have to change a bounds to <7 to loop through sel. Although this partially works, it skips the cases of 111 for a and b and 11 for sel.

Furthermore, I decided to test the bits manually for all cases, and it's showing the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because your end condition (`b < 8`) is always true.  You can easily prove this to yourself with the following code.  You can see 0-7 repeating many times:

```
module tb;

reg [2:0] b;
initial begin
    for (b = 0;b < 8;b=b+1) begin
        $display(b);
        #50;
    end
end
initial #1000 $finish;

endmodule
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
0
1
2
3
```

Since you declared `b` as a 3-bit signal, it's range of values is 0 through 7.  Therefore, b is always less than 8.  When b=7, b+1=0, not 8.

Changing 8 to 7 displays only 0-6 once because the end condition (`b < 7`) becomes false.

Here is one way to loop from 0 to 7 once:

```
module tb;

reg [2:0] b;
initial begin
    b = 0;
    repeat (8) begin
        $display(b);
        #50;
        b=b+1;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Another common way is to declare `b` as an `integer` instead of a 3-bit `reg`.  Then `for (b = 0;b < 8;b=b+1) begin` loops 0-7 once because b can increase to 8. An `integer` is a 32-bit signed value (refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 6.11 Integer data types).